# interact.js dragged item move on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, interact.js

it's my first time to use this plugin.

I want to add a stacking of elements whenever it's dragged. I use z-index and position relative.

```
    onstart: function (event) {

    //get max z-index on page   
      var maxZ = Math.max.apply(null, 
      $.map($('body > *'), function(e,n) {
        if ($(e).css('position') != 'static')
          return parseInt($(e).css('z-index')) || 1;
      }));

        event.target.style.background = 'red';
        event.target.style.zIndex = maxZ + 1; 
        event.target.style.position = 'relative'; 
    },
```

Is there more efficient way to do this?

[original drag and drop demo](http://interactjs.io/)

[my edited drag and drop demo with stacking](http://jsfiddle.net/juancoder/vz7ofxqt/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works well if the elements are *not* also used as dropzones. When dropzones overlap, interact.js chooses the element that is deepest in the DOM and so should appear above the other dropzones ulness some CSS properties change the drawing order (eg. `position`, `transform`, `z-index`, etc.) If overlapping dropzones are re-ordered with `z-index` then it might happen that the drop targets look incorrect.

If the elements that you're targeting are all siblings and all have `absolute` or `fixed` `position` (before any drag happens), then appending one element to it's parent should bring it in front of the others without using `z-index` so drop checks should work fine.

```
onstart: function (event) {
    var target = event.target;

    // Bring element in front of its siblings
    target.parentNode.appendChild(target);

    ...
}
```